# How to include third party script into background.js

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I want to include this script `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wrangr/psl/master/dist/psl.min.js` into my `background.js` and use it like:

```
var url = tabs[0].url;
url = url.split("/")[2];
var domain = psl.parse(url);
```

where `psl` is coming from the included script.

What is the correct syntax for including the script in the `background.js`?

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages#manifest

Comment: @wOxxOm could you give more details? I don't really follow you. The link you give is about registering local scripts in `manifest.json`. But i want to include remote script with something like `<script src="..."></script>`  in `background.js`, which is already registered in `manifest.json`.

Comment: Loading remote scripts in the super privileged context of an extension is a really terrible idea, don't do that.

Comment: Ah, ok - didn't know that, thank you! Then i should save the script as local script, register it in the manifest. And - here rises another question - how can i pass and use a function from it in `background.js`?

Comment: Yes. The scripts will share the same global scope (and `window` or `self` object) so you can use global functions directly as though they're in the same script. Just make sure to include the library scripts before background.js

Comment: Hmm, i was even forced to pass a variable from background.js to popup.js to become able to use variable, defined in background, in popup - thats why i ask here too... Well ok, will test and report)